# filter data return with javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

i have function selectcountry(val) on click show the id,name,firstname in search-box
i want to  filter salary from the query  and show it in other search box

```
 $keyword1 = "";
    $keyword2 = "";
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    if(!empty($keyword)) {
        
           if(strpos($keyword," ") == false){
              $keyword1 = '%'.$keyword.'%';
              $query = "SELECT salaire,_id,name,firstName FROM ap_personnel  WHERE name LIKE '".$keyword1."' OR firstName LIKE '".$keyword1."' OR telephone LIKE '".$keyword1."' OR _id LIKE '".$keyword1."'  limit 10";
                 }
                 
          else{
              $pos = strpos($keyword," ");
              $keyword1 = '%'.substr($keyword,0,$pos).'%';
              $keyword2 = '%'.substr($keyword,$pos+1,strlen($keyword)).'%';
               $query = "SELECT salaire,name,firstName,_id FROM ap_personnel WHERE  name LIKE '".$keyword1."' AND firstName LIKE '".$keyword2."' OR firstName LIKE '".$keyword1."' AND name LIKE '".$keyword2."' OR telephone LIKE '".$keyword1."' OR _id LIKE '".$keyword1."'  LIMIT 10";
                }      
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    
    if(!empty($result)) {
        
    ?>
    <ul id="country-list">
    <?php
    foreach($result as $country) {
    
    ?>
    <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $country["_id"]. " ".$country["name"]." ".$country["firstName"]?>');">
    <?php echo $country["_id"]." ".$country["name"]." ".$country["firstName"];?></li>
    
    <?php } ; 
function selectCountry(data) {
$("#search-box").val(data);
$("salary").val(must be salary);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a `WHERE salaire $filter` at the end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just pass the salary value as a second argument.

```
onClick="selectCountry('<?= $country["_id"]. " ".$country["name"]." ".$country["firstName"]?>', '<?= $country['salaire']?>');
```

and then change your function to:

```
function selectCountry(data, salary) {
    $("#search-box").val(data);
    $("#salary").val(salary);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

*Notice that I also added `#` on `$('#salary)` to make it select the element with that id.*